# Tor process gets jammed, hidden services won't resolve

Tags: onion-services

I'm dealing with a situation here. I'm attempting to run a webserver over a few hidden services. I've set up my torrc file to contain a few hidden services.
And then run just well. But then after a few hours, or sometimes minutes, the sites will become unreachable. Only when I run service tor restart does the issue fix itself, until it gets jammed again, and et cetra. Looking at torrc, I can see that it has to do with circuit building.

As a note, I haven't shared these hidden services with anyone, so an attack can't even be an option, I assume.

What could be the problem? And how can I fix it?

Relevant log snippet from `/var/log/tor/notices.log`

```
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [notice] Application request when we haven't used client functionality lately. Optimistically trying known bridges again.
...
Mar 29 03:40:24.000 [warn] Giving up on launching a rendezvous circuit to $[censored]~ at [IP addr redacted] for hidden service [hidden service onion redacted]
Mar 29 03:40:27.000 [warn] Giving up on launching a rendezvous circuit to $[censored]~ at [IP addr redacted] for hidden service [hidden service onion redacted]
Mar 29 03:40:31.000 [warn] Giving up on launching a rendezvous circuit to $[censored]~ at [IP addr redacted] for hidden service [hidden service onion redacted]
Mar 29 03:40:34.000 [warn] Giving up on launching a rendezvous circuit to $[censored]~ at [IP addr redacted] for hidden service [hidden service onion redacted]
Mar 29 03:40:37.000 [warn] Giving up on launching a rendezvous circuit to $[censored]~ at [IP addr redacted] for hidden service [hidden service onion redacted]
```

Thanks all, and stay safe